# Python 2^i sum. Difficulty with for loop formation

Tags: python, printing

I am trying to write a python program to print 2^i. For range 1..10. For each element I do not want the actual sum to display but rather the code to look like:

```
When i=1, you have 2^1=2
When i=2, you have 2^2+2^2=2*2^2
When i=3, you have 2^3+2^3+2^3=3*2^3
```

This is what I have written so far.

```
n = 10
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print "2**", i, "equal to:", 2**i
```

The problem with this code is it displays the result of 2**i not in the format I had mentioned above. Any help would be appreciated I am stuck.

Comment: Python uses `**` as the power operator, not `^`! Didn't `2^ 3 equal to: 1` make you suspect something is *fishy*? What you are actually calculating is the [Binary XOR](http://www.xcprod.com/titan/XCSB-DOC/binary_xor.html) of `2` and `3` in that case.

Comment: Well, you apparently want `i*2^i`, not `2^i` and the operator you want is probably `2**i`. `^` is the XOR operator

Comment: do you want to print the out put like 2^1=2,  2^2+2^2=2*2^2,...?

Comment: Put another way, is the output you are showing the *exact* output you want, or just a stand-in for something else? In the latter case, please edit your question with the *exact* output for the first few iterations.

Comment: Yes I want the exact output to look like 2^1 =2, 2^2 + 2^2 = 2*2^2 and so forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just wanted to wrap `i` to be a `str`, rather than `int`.
If yes, one liner print statement for your code becomes:

```
print "2^{}{}".format(i, "+2^{}".format(i)*(i-1)), "equal to: ", i, "*2^", i
```

A cleaner version supported by both *Python2* and *Python3*:

```
n = 10
for i in range(1,n+1):
    base = '+2^{}'.format(i)
    result = ' equal to: {0}*2^{0}'.format(i)
    print('{}{}{}'.format(base[1:], base*(i-1), result))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes sense, I will implement this idea into my solution.